# Move a PyQt slider based on maya timeline

Tags: python, pyqt5, maya, pyside2

I've this question that has tangled my brain for so many days by now. It possible to connect a pyqt slider value onto a Maya current time change? I have a slider that represents the rotation value, if these values are keyframed and change over time the slider doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maya time slider change event ( from the cmds.scriptJob() ) 
If you want to change time with the slider, you have to use PyQt.